# There is no Bluetooth connection between the Android application and Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi

There is no connection between Raspberry Pi and the Android application I made.

I'm building an application that connects to Raspberry Pi 4 with Bluetooth and receives data. However, when attempting to access Raspberry Pi with an application, the pairing lasted only a few seconds, then disconnected again and became unreachable.I installed an essential library on Raspberry Pi, and I even completed registering my Android device. I couldn't check what the problem was even when I looked at the code. I wonder if the code has changed since the new "permissioncheck" was created in June 2022, so it doesn't work properly.I want to know why this problem occurs.

**MainActivity Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
    TextView mTvBluetoothStatus;
    TextView mTvReceiveData;
    TextView mTvSendData;
    Button mBtnBluetoothOn;
    Button mBtnBluetoothOff;
    Button mBtnConnect;
    Button mBtnSendData;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices;
    List<String> mListPairedDevices;

    Handler mBluetoothHandler;
    ConnectedBluetoothThread mThreadConnectedBluetooth;
    BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;
    BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;

    final static int BT_REQUEST_ENABLE = 1;
    final static int BT_MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    final static int BT_CONNECTING_STATUS = 3;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    final static UUID BT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private String Tag;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTvBluetoothStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBluetoothStatus);
        mTvReceiveData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvReceiveData);
        mTvSendData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvSendData);
        mBtnBluetoothOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBluetoothOn);
        mBtnBluetoothOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBluetoothOff);
        mBtnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        mBtnSendData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendData);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setTitle("Need Bluetooth Access");
                builder.setMessage("Need location Access");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, 2 );
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setTitle("Need Bluetooth Access");
                builder.setMessage("Need location Access");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT}, 3 );
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }


        mBtnBluetoothOn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bluetoothOn();
            }
        });
        mBtnBluetoothOff.setOnClickListener(view -> bluetoothOff());
        mBtnConnect.setOnClickListener(view -> listPairedDevices());
        mBtnSendData.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (mThreadConnectedBluetooth != null) {
                mThreadConnectedBluetooth.write(mTvSendData.getText().toString());
                mTvSendData.setText("");
            }
        });
        mBluetoothHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == BT_MESSAGE_READ) {
                    String readMessage = null;
                    readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    mTvReceiveData.setText(readMessage);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    void bluetoothOn() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device does not support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mTvBluetoothStatus.setText("Activation");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intentBluetoothEnable = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                startActivityForResult(intentBluetoothEnable, BT_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            }
        }
    }

    void bluetoothOff() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mTvBluetoothStatus.setText("Deactivation");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions [], int [] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("Debugging", "coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Restrict Permissions");
                    builder.setMessage("BT cannot be retrieved and associated because location information and access are not allowed");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case BT_REQUEST_ENABLE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mTvBluetoothStatus.setText("Enable");
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mTvBluetoothStatus.setText("Disable");
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    void listPairedDevices() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Check Device");

                mListPairedDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevices) {
                    mListPairedDevices.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                final CharSequence[] items = mListPairedDevices.toArray(new CharSequence[mListPairedDevices.size()]);
                mListPairedDevices.toArray(new CharSequence[mListPairedDevices.size()]);

                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        connectSelectedDevice(items[item].toString());
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no paired devices.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void connectSelectedDevice(String selectedDeviceName) {
        for (BluetoothDevice tempDevice : mPairedDevices) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissionson
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            if (selectedDeviceName.equals(tempDevice.getName())) {
                mBluetoothDevice = tempDevice;
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BT_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error occurred while connecting to Bluetooth.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();}
        catch(IOException e) {
            try
            {
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e2)
            {
                Log.e(Tag, "Close socket", e2);
            }
        }

        mThreadConnectedBluetooth = new ConnectedBluetoothThread(mBluetoothSocket);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mThreadConnectedBluetooth.start();

    }

    private class ConnectedBluetoothThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedBluetoothThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error connecting socket.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.available();
                    if (bytes != 0) {
                        SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        bytes = mmInStream.available();
                        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        mBluetoothHandler.obtainMessage(BT_MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void write(String str) {
            byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error transferring data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error releasing socket", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```